# View Google Analytics on another site

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

*Just checking this is correct and I'm not gunna make a hash of my stats....*

I have a website, www.mydomain.com and I have signed up to a third party service on www.notmydomain.com/mypage

I already have Google Analytics set up on www.mydomain.com and would like to view stats from /mypage within the same account.

After reading [tracking multiple domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains) I think that I need to add the following code the the HEAD on /mypage

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-650003-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

This is using the same UA* code as on www.mydomain.com and I'm obviously specifying the same domain here too.

**Questions**:

1) Is the above the correct way to do this?

2) Would I have to change the GA code snippet on mydomain.com to match the one above? (It 
already does everything except _setDomainName and  _setAllowLinker )

3) Would the same work for subdomains on my own site, e.g. mysubdomain.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

As for 1), I believe that your code is indeed the correct way to do this. I am currently tracking multiple subdomains using this method.

If you want 3), you need to do 2).

Answer (score 0):

Re 3, the following is sufficient for tracking across multiple subdomains:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
```

However, strictly speaking you should add a leading period to the domain name, like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mydomain.com']);
```

It should still work without it but this should ensure better cross-browser compliance.

The line:

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
```

is only required for cross-domain tracking.  It also needs to appear on www.notmydomain.com/mypage.

Don't forget you also need to add a linker function to all the links from mydomain.com to notmydomain.com (and vice-versa if you think visitors might start their visit from notmydomain.com).